# Touchpad not working after suspending Laptop [14.10]

Tags: laptop, touchpad, 14.10

My touchpad stops working after closing and reopening my laptop. This problem exists since upgrading to 14.10 from 14.04. I have to reboot Ubuntu to get it working again. I already tried rmmod psmouse, but it only gives me this error:

```
rmmod: ERROR: Module psmouse is not currently loaded
```

my xinput list is as follows:
http://pastebin.com/wL8XhNve

Can someone help me identify this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I've just tried the script mentioned here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+s...079/comments/7 (copied below) with a positive result.

```
This is what I did to fix this for me:

# sudo touch /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_touchpad
# sudo chmod 755 /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_touchpad

Then edit the file 10_touchpad and paste the following into it:

#!/bin/sh
case "${1}" in
     resume|thaw)
             rmmod hid_multitouch
             modprobe hid_multitouch
             ;;
esac
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. I have the same exact problem. I also tried to update my linux kernel, as many said would fix the problem. Now i'm on 3.18 and still the problem persists.

Comment: Worked for me, with Acer Aspire E 15 running 14.04Trusty.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the touchpad entry is showing "ELAN0501:00 04F3:300B UNKNOWN". Is it taken when the touchpad is working or when it is down? Can you live boot from 14.04 and check the output?

Also share your laptop model info which might help others support you better.

A few pointers in case the output is the same:
I had a problem with Sony VAIO earlier where I had to use scripts to toggle the touchpad as it wouldn't work. More of a keybind issue but this is what I did:
http://tuxdiary.com/2014/03/07/toggle-sony-vaio-touchpad-on-ubuntu-14-04/

And here's how to run scripts on suspend/resume:
http://tuxdiary.com/2013/07/23/suspend-on-lid-close-on-lxde-ubuntu/

Comment: In 14.04 it shows as PS/2 Elantech Touchpad, but it doesn't work in the live boot. Before installing Ubuntu 14.10 it worked, after I installed a small fix for the multitouch. The Laptop is a Acer Aspire E5-571G-78QY with an i7-4510U. I already tried 'synclient touchpadoff=0' but it didn't help.

Comment: I have the same issue, with the same model! (Well, almost the same, an E5-571G-941Y).

Comment: Other people having the same issue: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2250002

Answer (score 0):

The suggested `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` hooks may not make an effect if `systemd-sleep` is doing the suspend instead of `pm-suspend` commannd; this may be the case if, for example, you are using Xfce's exit/suspend menu instead of `pm-suspend` from the commannd line.

I needed some time to understand this; thanks to https://askubuntu.com/a/643793/19753.

So I have put (additionally to `/etc/pm/sleep.d/75touchpad` which contains in my case the common `modprobe psmouse`-workaround mentioned by OP) the file `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/my-touchpad` (executable):

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1/$2" in
  post/suspend)
      exec /etc/pm/sleep.d/75touchpad resume
      ;;
  post/hybrid-sleep)
      /etc/pm/sleep.d/75touchpad thaw
      exec /etc/pm/sleep.d/75touchpad resume
      ;;
  post/*) # hibernate
      exec /etc/pm/sleep.d/75touchpad thaw
      ;;
  pre/suspend)
      exec /etc/pm/sleep.d/75touchpad suspend
      ;;
  pre/hybrid-sleep)
      /etc/pm/sleep.d/75touchpad suspend
      exec /etc/pm/sleep.d/75touchpad hibernate
      ;;
  pre/*) # hibernate
      exec /etc/pm/sleep.d/75touchpad hibernate
      ;;
esac
```

It's a kind of a universal proxy to call a script originally put for pm-utils.