# Suspend hook not working in Xubuntu 15.04

Tags: xubuntu, suspend

I've been using [this suspend hook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152403/how-do-i-make-changes-to-proc-acpi-wakeup-permanent?answertab=votes#tab-top) with Ubuntu & Kubuntu since the days of 12.10, however when I did a clean install of Xubuntu 15.04 yesterday, I noticed it suddenly not working. I've created a file `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/45fixusbwakeup` copied the script into it, and made it executable with `sudo chmod +x /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/45fixusbwakeup` as I always did before. I'm not an expert, and this hook has always been working from me, so I don't have a clue what could be wrong now.

What I basically need is that these 3 commands execute every time before computer is going to sleep, or at every startup:

```
sudo -s
echo USB0 > /proc/acpi/wakeup
echo USB2 > /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

I would also like to note that when I suspend via terminal command `sudo pm-suspend` the script works flawlessly, it's only not working via traditional logout--->suspend button in Xubuntu, so I guess this is something Xubuntu-related. I guess it actually suspends via `xfce4-session-logout --suspend` and that's creating the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> xfce4-session will use systemd-sleep on a systemd system (not pm-suspend). systemd-sleep hooks should be put in /lib/systemd/system-sleep using the following template:

```
#!/bin/sh
case $1/$2 in
  pre/*)
    echo "Going to $2..."
    ;;
  post/*)
    echo "Waking up from $2..."
    ;;
esac
```

> ...and made executable. One other caveat with systemd is that the
>   scripts in this directory are run concurrently, not sequentially based
>   on name (as is the case with pm-utils).

Answer (score 1):

#### To run the commands on startup

Place the commands (remove `sudo -s`) into a **.sh** file and make it executable with `chmod +x <filename>`.

Create a *new* bash script containing `gksudo -s root <path_to_other_bash_script>` and make it executable.

Create a file with a **.desktop** suffix in the `~/.config/autostart` directory - create the folder if you don't have it.

Place the following into the **.desktop** file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=name_of_second_bash_script
Exec=path/to/second/script
Type=Application
```

The commands present in the bash script will be run on startup.

Comment: `sudo -s` will ask for the password.

Comment: modify it to `gksu -s root` - it'll prompt you for the `sudo` password on startup.

Comment: `gksu -s root` obviously don't do as same as `sudo -s`. After `gksu -s root`, and entering password, next command, `echo USB0 > /proc/acpi/wakeup` results in `bash: /proc/acpi/wakeup: Permission denied`.

Comment: Of course, I didn't think of that - see the edit

Comment: Now it doesn't prompt me for the password on startup, and of course, does not get the job done.

Comment: @Reloader Oops... my mistake :) new edit ;-) If that doesn't work you don't have `gksudo` installed on your system.

Comment: I guess you didn't try it... it simply echos the string `USB0 > /proc/acpi/wakeup; echo USB2 > /proc/acpi/wakeup`.

Comment: I tried, it prompt for a password at the login, but it doesn't change `/proc/acpi/wakeup/` settings. Meanwhile, I edited the question, I need a way to change default Xubuntu suspend command to `pm-suspend`, because script works that way.

Comment: @Reloader 
Been thinking it over and made another edit: "Create a new bash script containing `gksudo -s root <path_to_other_bash_script>` and make it executable." This isn't related to your last comment btw.